# How do I filter email with attachments using IMAP on PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter, imap, attachment

I'm trying to filter email with attachments using IMAP on PHP(CI) to mark attachments on mail list page. But it take a long time..
Previously, I've classified emails by size but it didn't work on the mail without attachments but more than the set size.
How can I check the mail having attachments on mail list page quickly?

(The numbers 0 and 15 below are the test numbers of the mail list page.)

```
public function mail_list(){
  $mbox = $this->input->get("boxname");
  $mbox = (isset($mbox))? $mbox : "INBOX";
  $mails= $this->connect_mailserver($mbox);
    if($mails) {
      $mailno_arr = array();
      $mailno_arr_tmp = imap_sort($mails, SORTDATE, 1);
      for($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {
        $body = imap_body($mails, $mailno_arr_tmp[$i]);
        $res = (strpos($body, 'Content-Disposition: attachment')!=null)?  "1" : "0";
        $arr = array(
          "no" => $mailno_arr_tmp[$i],
          "attachments" => $res
        );
        array_push($mailno_arr, $arr);
      }
      $data['mailno_arr'] = $mailno_arr;
   }
   imap_close($mails);
   $this->load->view('mailbox/mail_list_v', $data);
}

public function connect_mailserver($mbox="") {
  $mailserver = $this->mailserver;
  $host = "{" . $mailserver . ":143/imap/novalidate-cert}$mbox";
  $user_id = $this->user_id;
  $user_pwd = $this->user_pwd;
  return @imap_open($host, $user_id, $user_pwd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you’re looking for, but if using sonething like [EmailEngine](https://emailengine.app/) you could use the [message listing endpoint](https://api.emailengine.app/#operation/getV1AccountAccountMessages) and check if the attachments property is set or not.

If you want to do this yourself, not use external software, then unfortunately IMAP does not provide attachment specific search capabilities but there are multiple options how to perform message listings and the approach you are using (list message bodies and do a string search) is indeed the slowest option. Instead of using imap_body, use [imap_fetchstructure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) as it would include all the information you need without downloading the message body. Dowside is that it’s kind of hard to interpret.